# Python unexpected EOF while parsing 2.7.10

Tags: python

This is a bit of unfinished code to create a calculator, However it keeps on giving me a syntax error.

```
n1=input("Enter Number: ")
Eo=input("Enter Operator: ")
if Eo=="+" or "-" or "*" or "/":
    answer= n1+str(Eo)+input("Enter 2nd number: ")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Programming/Calculator.py", line 2, in <module>
    Eo=input("Enter Operator: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    +
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: This line doesn't do what you think it does: `if Eo=="+" or "-" or "*" or "/":`

Comment: Also see [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15112149) as you are making a logic error in your `if` test.

Comment: What does it do then?, I want it to do the answer calculation when one of the operators have been selected..

Comment: Please write a program that writes hundred times: "I will not use `input` with Python 2.x until I can explain in detail what it does."

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1) Use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

2) To check `Eo` against multiple values, use

```
if Eo in ("+", "-", "*", "/"):
```